# Google Mobile Ads iOS SDK Version does not increment

Tags: ios, iphone, admob, google-ads-api

I have the Google Mobile Ads SDK in my iOS app. I was previously on v7.0 of the SDK, but am upgrading to v7.9.1. There has been a warning printed to the console since I was on v7.0:

> You are currently using version 7.0.0 of the SDK. Please consider
>   updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest
>   features and bug fixes. The latest SDK can be downloaded from
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/download. A full list of
>   release notes is available at
>   https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes.

After upgrading to v7.9.1, which is the SDK available at the link provided, I still get the same SDK version warning. I ran my app and printed the SDK version by calling `GADRequest.sdkVersion()` and it still prints 7.0. Where am I going wrong here that's preventing the SDK from recognizing what version it is? I am also using the Google Interactive Media Ads SDK, which is on version 3.2.1, but I don't think that's affecting it.